# iFrame implementation on Wordpress (DIVI) site

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I have the following problem, one of our customers wants to have a certain animated graphic on one of their pages.

[graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuwVv.png)

[link](https://sinerefl.sirv.com/qualicut/qualicut.spin)

It's basically a metal nut that u can turn with your mouse wheel to see what services they offer regarding production.

On the old website they had, it implemented like [this](https://newqualicut.qualicut.ch/leistungsspektrum-in-technischen-werten/)
Nicely, fullscreen with scrolling functionality.

However, when I try to use an iframe to implement the graphic it looks like [this](https://www.qualicut.ch/technische-werte) (scroll to the bottom to see the graphic)

The code I use for the iframe is the following:

```html
<iframe class="fuenfeck" src="https://sinerefl.sirv.com/qualicut/qualicut.spin">
</iframe>
```

I already tried to add width attribute but it only makes the container larger, not the graphic. I'm new to the whole iframe stuff, so I really need your help =)

Thanks and regards!

Comment: set height and width attributes as describes here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you observe their css you will find somthing like that, that is useful for the iframe to be adaptative :

```css
.responsive-iframe {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 62.5%;
}

.responsive-iframe iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-iframe"><iframe class="fuenfeck" src="https://sinerefl.sirv.com/qualicut/qualicut.spin">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

any particular reason you want to use an iFrame? A much better way of embedding a Sirv Spin is to follow these instructions - https://sirv.com/help/articles/sirv-spin/#embed-a-360-spin

```
<script src="https://scripts.sirv.com/sirv.js"></script>
<div class="Sirv" data-src="https://sinerefl.sirv.com/qualicut/qualicut.spin"></div>
```

There's also a WordPress plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/sirv/ which is Divi compatible

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! I didnt know what "Sirv" is so i didnt think about :)

Comment: Glad that helped. I've forgotten to mention that there's also a new version of Sirv Spin with tonnes of improvements, and it's a matter of replacing the js snippet. You can find the docs here https://sirv.com/help/articles/360-spin/